# Change Navigation Color in a fullPage Slider Lib

Tags: javascript, css, colors, slider, fullpage.js

I have successfully used that [lib](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/).

I used the example, where you have navigation Dots on the right.
Now everything is working fine, but I have one Problem:
I cannot change the color of the Navigation dots on the right side.
I have changed every color that I was able to find in the given CSS file but none of them changed anything.

One of my slides looks like that:

[image]

And on the right you will find the navigation dots that should be white and not grey:

[image]

I know that this is not a question that is helpful for many other people. But I would be very thankful for help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ref `https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/199`

You only have to overwrite the dots navigation styles:

```
#fullPage-nav span, .fullPage-slidesNav span
#fullPage-nav li a, .fullPage-slidesNav li a
#fullPage-nav li, .fullPage-slidesNav li
#fullPage-nav ul, .fullPage-slidesNav ul
#fullPage-nav
.fullPage-tooltip
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason is that the dots are added with a script. It might be a good idea to use Chrome-inspector to see what the name is of the element and then either override that in your own css or check the script-file, look for that element and change the color there

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me

```css
span {
    background: white!important;
}
```